# Connector type for a plug-in short-circuit

Tags: connector

I am looking for a product, type of a connector (2 pin, panel-mount) that also has a something to plug into it which will short-circuit the two pins. Is there any name for such a connector? (or only the short-circuiting plug)

Comment: Something like a jumper?

Comment: There are also BNC shorts. If you would consider using a BNC connector rather than a two-pin connector. There are shorting dust caps available that can be secured with a chain so they don't get lost. https://www.pasternack.com/50-ohm-bnc-male-short-cap-with-4-inch-chain-pe6127-p.aspx

Comment: Be aware that anything designed to make or break a short circuit under heavy current might have more to its design than meets the eye ....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you want is called a jumper, or jumper link, or pin jumper, I've seen it called a lot of things.

[image: A jumper shorting two pins on a five-pin header]

[Here](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sullins-connector-solutions/QPC02SXGN-RC/S9337-ND/2618262) is one from a quick search on digi-key. They're designed to short out two adjacent pins on a 0.1" (2.54 mm) pin header, such as [this one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/harwin-inc/M20-9990246/952-2262-ND/3728226).

---

[image: A double banana plug with the two plugs shorted together]

If you want something that looks nicer, you can get one of [these](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/pomona-electronics/5145/501-1480-ND/737158), which is designed to plug into two adjacent banana jacks and short them together. This one can also handle more current than the jumper.

---

[image: Ten shorting links]

And as one last thing, [this](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/banana-and-tip-connectors-accessories/351?k=shorting%20bar) is a shorting bar, or shorting link; you see them fairly often in multi-channel bench power supplies to short together two channels (for a bipolar supply, for example). They go around binding posts and are designed to hang from one of the binding posts when not in use, which helps with not losing them. This one, though, is more something you'd see in an electronics lab than in an end product.

Answer (score 4):

You can, of course, simply take any handy connector (perhaps a 1/4" phone plug) and short the terminals inside the plug yourself.